# What does Cassandra's JMX metric TombstoneScannedHistogram RecentValues mean?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

For Cassandra's JMX metric `TombstoneScannedHistogram` RecentValues mean?

```
$ nodetool sjk mxdump -q "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=my_keyspace,scope=Person,name=TombstoneScannedHistogram"

"RecentValues" : [ 641, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
```

For example, does the `45` in the above example, mean for that time duration, there were `45` tombstones that were scanned for a single query?

Answer (score 1):

Histogram describes number of occurrences at each level, where level is calculated as series where next value is 1.2 greater than previous, so it will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14, .... until 25109160 (see [this slide](https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/storing-cassandra-metrics-chris-lohfink-datastax-c-summit-2016/36) and all other slides if you interested about internals).

in this case, it means that there were 641 cases of 1 tombstone, then there were 23 cases of M tombstones, and 45 cases of N tombstones (you calculate M & N as per formula).  There same way other histograms are calculated - for latencies, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. Is there a reason why the histogram uses that formula "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14, .... until 25109160"? If you hadn't replied, I would've thought the `641`, `23` in my example means there are 641 and 23 tombstones.